# InstallShield doesn't create one big Setup-file

Tags: installation, installshield

I have created a project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and I have activated Installshield so that I can create a setup-file for my project. The deal is that InstallShield doesn't create one big setup-file, but rather one folder which contains a setup-file I can run to install the project. If I take the setup-file out of the folder, the setup will fail. Do anyone know what I am doing wrong? I feel like the whole purpose of creating a setup-file is to only have one exe-file, not to be forced to go through a folder to find a setup-file.

Added an image of my folder:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a variety of scenarios that call for different build configurations.  A single self extracting EXE is not always desired.

However, if that is what you desire, build the Single Image configuration instead.

Personally, if you don't have a reason to have a Setup.exe  ( setup prereqs, multiple instances, minor upgrades and so on ) then I'd just build it as a single MSI.

Answer (score 25):

Within Visual Studio click Build from the menu bar, then click configuration manager. Within the Configuration Manager dialog, set the Configuration to SingleImage and then rebuild the project.

Comment: Even the single image produces , the same structure as for a DVD.

Comment: I got it now , compression needs to be enabled for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having this same issue but all the solutions are either based on LE or pre 2013 versions.

So, since the SingleImage is not available in InstallShield Premier 2013 do the following:

- In the Release Wizard select Media Type: Web
- Web Type: One Executable

This should generate a unique self-contained exe file